# how to ADD a one list to another in python?

Tags: python

im trying to write a fun script for a password generator that DOES NOT have any rational connection to the user, thus making it alot harder to use the fact you know the user in order to guess it.. but im new to python

basically i know how to use append and extend but i was trying to find a way to add a whole list to another, for example is `list1` is (1 2 3 4) and `list2 is (3 4 5 9) i want to know how to add`list2`to`list1` and get a list1: (1 2 3 4 3 4 5 9)

ty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done very simply using the extend method. The following is a quick demonstration:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = [3,4,5]
>>> l1.extend(l2)
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

The addition operator has the same effect:

```
>>> l1 + l2
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: this is EXACTLY what i've been looking for, not sure what i did wrong the first time that prevented this from working for me

Answer (score 2):

Just use the concatenate overloaded operator:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [3, 4, 5, 9]

list1 + list2
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 9]
```

The above will create a *new* list with the result of concatenating `list1` and `list2`. You can assign it to a new variable if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 ways (as far as I know). Let's:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
```

**First:**

```
list1 = list1 + list2
print list3
>>> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

**Second:**

```
list1.extend(list2)
print list1
>>> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Also remember that `(1,2,3)` is a `tuple` not a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Addition concatenates lists:

```
list1 + list2
```